# Period of oscillations of a pendulum made of two disks (K&K 6.15) [Solved]

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

This is my first question on Physics Stackexchange, so, please suggest any edits I should do to my post.

The question is:

> A pendulum is made of two disks each of mass M and radius R separated by a massless rod. One of the disks is pivoted through its center by a small pin. The disks hang in the same plane and their centres are a distance *l* apart. Find the period for small oscillations.

Now, I tried to compare this problem with the concept of **Physical Pendulum**. [image]

Now, I tried to find out the centre of mass of the system, so that I can apply the formula:

$\omega = \sqrt{\cfrac{gl}{k^2 + l^2}}$ where, l = distance between the pivot and the centre of mass.

Can someone please suggest whether I am on the right path or not and how should I proceed with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: and $k$ is what? I expect to see $R$ somewhere, don't you?

Comment: k is the radius of gyration, which in case of disk is $\sqrt{\cfrac{1}{2}}R$

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site, that "check my work" problems are considered off- topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a compound [pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum#Compound_pendulum) so you need to consider its [moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia), by using the [parallel axis theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) on its  [parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia)